# Error opening file written with rosbag?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm trying to follow the following tutorial so that I can incorporate reading and writing bag files into a program I'm creating:

h t t p : / / w i k i . r o s . o r g / r o s b a g / C o d e % 2 0 A P I # c p p _ a p i

However, there seems to be something going wrong with the writing to the file.  When I comment out the file reading section (because this part is causing errors upon compilation), and simply try to open the bag file written in a text editor, I get an error message, saying that the file cannot be read properly or something like that.  If I ignore the error, the resulting document looks really weird and has strange symbols and red coloration and just looks very wrong (I'm just trying to write a string and a number).

Anyone know what's going wrong/how to fix it? (I think the error in the reading section is being caused by incorrect writing of the file in the first place)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/117486/error-opening-file-written-with-rosbag?/) by [mysteriousmonkey29](https://answers.ros.org/users/9531/mysteriousmonkey29/) on ROS Answers with karma: 170 on 2014-01-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-01-13**:
What exactly are you doing? What is the exact error message that you get? What would you expect differently? Are you aware that rosbag files are a custom format? http://wiki.ros.org/Support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Compilation errors are not runtime errors, and will never be caused by a corrupt bag file. If you're having trouble compiling, there's a problem with your code or with one of the libraries.

Bag files are a binary format; they will not be readable in a standard text editor. You can read them with the [rosbag](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Commandline) command line tool, or using the [rqt_bag](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_bag) GUI tool.

If you can post samples of your code and the compilation errors you're seeing, you'll get more specific answers.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-01-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1